# Localhost:8080 showing blank page with react-native-web

Tags: typescript, react-native, localhost, react-native-web

i followed a tutorial for adding web support to a react native app. using react-native-web and webpack. looks like it works for everyone. but for me, i get a blank web page. even though it works just fine on the emulator.
i get no error in the console.
[image: and when i inspect the webpage i get this:]

[image: and this is my console:]

[this is the tutorial i followed:](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setup-react-native-web-app-with-typescript-and-webpack-ff79062f53ba)

as shown in the tutorial, i was hoping to see my simple react native code result both on the emulator and the webpage.

ps. my project is TypeScript based

this is my App.web.ts

```
   import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native'
import {name as appName} from './app.json'
import App from './App'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)

AppRegistry.runApplication(appName, {
  initialProps: {},
  rootTag: document.getElementById('app-root'),
})
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactnativewebapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "web":"cd web && webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and my index.js from which App.js should be rendered:

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Haven't messed around too much with web apps w/ RN.  But try running on a different port: 8081

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Without a code example it will be hard to us to help you out. Please try to provide a minimal code example in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.